# python parse special character in lxml

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

in my xml I have this line

```
<url>http://www.modeluxproperties.com/?act=list_web&m=search&purpose=sale&project=&type=32&beds=&lop=&Submit.x=37&Submit.y=20</url>
```

when i do this:

```
self.doc=etree.parse(xmlFile)
```

I got this error in that line :

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: EntityRef: expecting ';', line 5, column 56
```

Comment: It's parsing the ampersands in the URL as XML entities. I think the ampersands should be URL encoded -- try replacing all '&' with '&amp;'

Comment: @Kasapo thanks, write an answer to accept it please

Comment: Personally I doubt that this is enough. You have for instance `<`, `>`,... that need to be translated as wel (to `&lt;` and `&gt;`). Most programming languages have libraries to do this. Probably python as well although I don't know these.

Comment: @CommuSoft - the "<" and ">" surrounding the URL are perfectly valid XML characters and they should NOT be represented as XML entities. The reason being that the XML parser will parse `<url>` as an XML element rather than as plain text (which is what using an XML entity would do). If however the angle brackets were supposed to be in the URL, or anywhere in the XML element, then yes, they would also need to be encoded as XML entities. Using a URL-encode or XML-encode function/library should take care of encoding ampersands as well as other invalid XML entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's parsing the ampersands in the URL as XML entities. I think the ampersands should be URL encoded -- try replacing all `&` with `&amp;`